# Carousel on popup - Show 3 slides with different opacities

Tags: javascript, video, popup, modal-dialog, carousel

I've created a list of images that when you click on one of them, a video carousel pops up.

Everything works as expected, except that I would like to display 3 slides of the video carousel at the same time, where the active slide (the one in the middle) is opacity 1 but the other two (on the left and right) are opacity 0.5.

Could you help me?

This is how it works: https://codepen.io/sonder15478/pen/QvVPMq

```
See codepen link
```

Here is an image of what I mean with the opacities and how I would like the carousel to look:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is make all `.slick-slide` have a `0.5` opacity except for `.slick-current`.

```
.slick-slide {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  variableWidth: true
 });
```

```css
img {
  margin: 0 30px;
}

.slick-slide {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class="slider">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150?text=1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150?text=2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150?text=3">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150?text=4">
</section>
```

Comment: Why use different slider libraries? Anyway, it would be the same thing with anything: make sure that you have some class that tells you which element is the current element, then fade out all the other ones.

Comment: You're right. The problem is that I am unable to show 3 slides at the same time (like the picture) when the carousel pops up. Do you know how to apply the slick carousel to the pop up with the code that I gave? Thank you